# How to filter a numeric value with spaces using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to python and using version 3.8. I use regex to filter strings, special characters and numbers from a string. There are spaces in between characters and numbers and i try to filter them. I am able to filter the string upto first number. I am unable to filter the string till the last number.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
s = 'abc (efg): 2.1 296.2'
s1 = re.search(r'abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)(\d+)',s)
print(s1.group())

o/p
abc (efg):  2


s = 'abc (efg): 2.1 296.2'
s1 = re.search(r'abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)(\d+)(\s+)(\d+)',s)
print(s1.group())

o/p
    print(s1.group())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: `\d+` isn't going to match `2.1` or `296.2`

Comment: Use `[\d.]+` to match a number that can contain decimals.

Comment: If you aren't familiar with https://regex101.com already, I would highly suggest you use it or some site like it. I find it very helpful to not only test my regexes but also to learn from the explanations panel on the right.

Comment: @Barmar as long as you aren't worried about matching something like `9...0.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `\d` is looking for a digit, not a decimal. You've got several options to address this.

One option is,

```
abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)[\d.]+(\s+)[\d.]+
```

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/0wHsiy/1).

NOTE: The last two numbers can match incorrectly formatted numbers, e.g. `1.2.3`, etc. which may or may not be a problem in your case. We can't tell without more sample data.

If you want it to be super strict,

```
abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)[\d]+\.[\d]+(\s+)[\d]+\.[\d]+
```

[See in action](https://regex101.com/r/SukeP4/1).

Answer (score 0):

It might be your regular expression, try this way:

```py
s1 = re.search(r'abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)(\d+(\.\d+)?) (\d+(\.\d+)?)', s)
```

Comment: This sounds very uncertain, and could use some elaboration on what's wrong and how this resolves that issue. As written, this reads more as a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex is that `\d+` won't match floating point numbers like `2.1` or `296.2`. It doesn't account for the decimal point.

For an example of a regex matching such a floating point number in a string see below. By making the decimal point and following digits optional, it will also match a whole number.

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'( \d+ (?: \. \d+ )? )', re.X)
>>> m = r.search('296.2')
>>> m.group()
'296.2'
>>> m = r.search('296')
>>> m.group()
'296'
```

This can then be incorporated into your larger regex.

```
>>> num_re = r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?'
>>> r = re.compile(rf'abc(\s+)\(efg\):(\s+)({num_re})(\s+)({num_re})')
>>> m = r.search('abc (efg): 2.1 296.2')
>>> m.groups()
(' ', ' ', '2.1', ' ', '296.2')
>>> m.group()
'abc (efg): 2.1 296.2'
```

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am able to filter the string upto first number. I am unable to filter the string till the last number. ..."*

The `\d` syntax will only match integer values *0 through 9*.

```
abc\s+\(efg\):\s+(?=\d)(\S+)
```

- `\s+(?=\d)`, any *white-space* followed by a digit
- `(\S+)`, capture any consecutive *non white-space* characters

Here is an example.

```py
s1 = re.search(r'abc\s+\(efg\):\s+(?=\d)(\S+)',s)
print(s1.group(1))
```

Output

```
2.1
```